# Django & Django ORM: performance improvements to bulk updating records

Tags: django, django-orm, django-2.2

I'm hoping this will be a really simple question.

I just wanted some advise on the bulk updating of records.

An example bulk update may go something like this:

```
for user in User.objects.all().iterator():
    user.is_active = False
    user.save()
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this on the database level using the Django ORM?

Would the following be more efficient:

```
User.objects.all().update(is_active=False)?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work, but be aware that the update command will be converted directly to a SQL command, without running anything you customized on `save` and without triggering the save signals. If in your case there is no problem and you are more worried with the performance, go for it.

From django docs:

> Be aware that the update() method is converted directly to an SQL statement. It is a bulk operation for direct updates. It doesn’t run any save() methods on your models, or emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling save()), or honor the auto_now field option. If you want to save every item in a QuerySet and make sure that the save() method is called on each instance, you don’t need any special function to handle that.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: I have decided to accept this answer out of the three so far (@WillemVanOnsem's and @DanielRoseman's) because it adds in the caveat regarding `post_save` triggers using the `.save()` method. Although this was not necessary for a bulk uplaod - it still helps to understand bulk queries like this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using `update` would be more efficient. That will do a single database call, instead of one per object.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. You can use `User.objects.all().update(is_active=False)`.

This will result in a *single* query that looks like:

```
UPDATE `auth_user`
SET `is_active` = 0
```

It will thus reduce the number of roundtrips to the database to *one*.